# TinyMCE angular code and link overlays do not work within angular reactive form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tinymce, ionic4, tinymce-4

we have the following setup, which seems to override each other:

- following the tinyMCE angular [integration docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#usingwithreactiveforms)
- angular reactive forms (angular 9), which are generated dynamicaly based on a type, eg. **html**:

```js
private generateFormConfig() {
    const formConfig = {};

    // ...

    formConfig[controlId] = new FormControl(
        value,
        Validators.compose(formValidators)
    );

    // ...
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(formConfig);
}
```

- the form is then rendered inside a ionic modal component also with a dynamic *ngFor:

```html
<ng-template #formItems let-definition="definition" let-data="data" let-path="path" let-errors="errors">
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let formItemConf of definition">
      <div [ngSwitch]="formItemConf.input" [class]="'input-wrp input-wrp--' + formItemConf.input">

        <ion-input *ngSwitchDefault [type]="formItemConf.type" [formControlName]="getFormItemId(path, formItemConf.id)" class="form-control"></ion-input>

        <editor *ngSwitchCase="'html'" [id]="formItemConf.id" [init]="{
              height: 300,
              resize: true,
              convert_urls: false,
              menubar: 'edit view format',
              plugins: 'paste link lists code',
              toolbar: 'undo redo |  formatselect bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | forecolor backcolor | paste removeformat | code',

              table_appearance_options: false,
              table_resize_bars: false,
              table_style_by_css: true,

              paste_data_images: true
            }" [initialValue]="getFormValue(formItemConf, data)" [formControlName]="getFormItemId(path, formItemConf.id)">
        </editor>

        <ion-select *ngSwitchCase="'select'" [formControlName]="getFormItemId(path, formItemConf.id)" class="form-control">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let option of formItemConf.options" [value]="option.value">{{option.label | translate}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>

        <ion-checkbox *ngSwitchCase="'boolean'" [formControlName]="getFormItemId(path, formItemConf.id)"></ion-checkbox>

        <!-- ... and so on -->

        <div class="error" *ngIf="hasError(errors, formItemConf.id)">{{errors[formItemConf.id]}}</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

This works all spotless, but if we try to use the **link** or **code** plugin of tinymce, which are using modals by itself, it is impossible to edit the content. Th reason as far as I can see is, that the underlying inputs are hijacking the form focus, if I try to click an input:

[image]

The tinyMCE overlay inputs become unusable by this.

Any idea what the reason could be and how to fix it, would be higly appreciated :) Maybe this is a "feature" of angular reactive forms and can be dissabled?

Comment: I updated the description, as the issue seems to originate from the way ion-modal behaves, not angular in itself.

Comment: checking out, whether I can just get around this issue by using [quill](https://quilljs.com/) via [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill)